# Django manually fail transaction after done with for loop

Tags: python, django, transactions

I'm trying to run over a for loop that validates objects and saves them, and I want to fail it all if at least one have failed, but only after going over all the objects. I've tried different approaches, but on all of them - even if there was an exception, at least one object was saved to DB. In the latest version, see below, I'm trying to set

```
transaction.set_rollback(True)
```

if at least on exception was raised.

```
try:
    is_failed = False
    with transaction.atomic():
        for identifier, spec in spec_dict.items():
            try:
                spec_data = {'title':my_title,
                             'identifier': identifier,
                             'updated_by': user_id,
                             'created_by': user_id
                }
                serializer = SpecSerializer(data=spec_data)
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                serializer.save()

            except DataError as DE:
                print("** in DataError")
                is_failed = True
                pass

            except ValidationError as VE:
                print("** in ValidationError")
                print(str(VE))
                is_failed = True
                pass

            except Exception as Exc:
                print("** inside Exception: " + str(Exc))
                is_failed = True
                pass

        if is_failed:
            transaction.set_rollback(True)
except IntegrityError:
    print("** inside integrity error")
    pass
```

Seems like the 'set_rollback' doesn't affect the transaction. Worth to mention that all our http requests are wrapped in transaction.

EDIT:
Should transaction.atomic() work for non view functions? Couldn't find answer for that

Comment: may be for loop is running after rollback, can you give break after rollback statement, if you want to mark it as failed

Comment: Please fix your whitespace, it's all over the place and affects the correctness of your code.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry - right, fixed.

Comment: Try it without catching `Exception`. That could be causing a violation of the transaction API (see [Avoid catching exceptions inside atomic!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly)) and masking the problem.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry - I tried it. Got the same results. I just know realized that it is run as an async task on Celery. Could that be the reason?

Comment: You'll have the same issue with `DataError`, actually, since it's a kind of database exception. If you want to continue through the loop in the face of database errors, you'll have to run each iteration in it's own `atomic()` block. I'm not sure if that will solve your problem (the code otherwise looks right to me) but it's a necessary step.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently -

```
transaction.atomic():
```

is managing the transaction for the 'default' DB by default, unless other DB is mentioned:

```
transaction.atomic(using='otherDB'):
```

Since we use more than one DB and the one that I worked on was not set as the default, I was missing the 'using'.